# Is there a relevant universal property for Fitting ideals?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a scheme and $\mathscr F$ a quasi-coherent sheaf on $S$, locally finitely presented. Set $S_{-1}=S$ and for all $n\geqslant 0$, let $S_n$ be the closed subscheme of $S$ defined by the $n$-th Fitting ideal sheaf of $\mathscr F$.
The following universal properties are well known:

1. As a closed *subset* of $S$, one can describe $S_n$ as the set of those $s$ such that $\dim_{\kappa(s)}\mathscr F\otimes \kappa(s)\geqslant n+1$.
2. The *scheme* $S_n\setminus S_{n+1}$ is the final object of the category of $S$-schemes turning $\mathscr F$ into a locally free sheaf of rank $n+1$.

But does it exist an interesting universal property for the whole scheme $S_n$ ? I think that the answer is likely negative, because if it were positive, it would likely be stated at standard places where Fitting ideals are defined, and one would avoid checking explicitly that their usual construction does not depend on the chosen presentation...

Comment: if $\phi: X \to Y$ is flat, of finitely type and of constant rel codim $d$, then $Sing \ \phi= V(Fitt_d \Omega_{X/Y})$. That's not a universal property but at least an interesting fact as I think (see Eisenbud's & Harris' "Geometry of Schemes" p 231)

Comment: Yes, but once again this is a set-theoretic, and not scheme-theoretic, description of Fitt.

Comment: Is the second proposition of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05P8 an answer to your question?

Comment: @Z.M : no, this is my statement 2 above. It describes the open subscheme $S_n\setminus S_{n+1}$ of $S_n$, not the whole of $S_n$.

Comment: Your statement 2 is the *third* proposition, I think.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But the second proposition does not describe the closed subscheme S_r, but rather it’s open complement, and is in fact equivalent to my statement 1.

Comment: Thanks, it's correct. The other statement looks like a stratification and constructibility, but there is a crucial difference between the étale coefficients and the quasicoherent coefficients: in the étale world, given a closed subscheme $Z\subseteq X$ with its open complement $U$, we have a recollement $D(Z)\to D(X)\to D(U)$, but the same picture is more subtle in the quasicoherent world.

Comment: I am not familiar with Fitting ideals, but one can remove part of presentation in the definition (this should be obvious, but I don't see anywhere using this). Let's consider the affine case, over $S=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Given an $R$-module $M$ of finite type, pick a surjection $R^{\oplus n}\to M$ and let $K$ denote its kernel. Then the $k$-th Fitting ideal is precisely the ideal generated by coordinates of the image of $\bigwedge^{n-k}K\to\bigwedge^{n-k}R^{\oplus n}$. I spent a couple of time trying to remove the choice of this surjection, but so far failed.

Comment: Yes, the point for étale cohomology is that it is insensitive to nilpotents, so it does not distinguish between two closed subschemes having the same underlying closed subset. 


I also tried to find an intrinsic description using exterior powers but was unsuccessful sofar. 


If you want a concrete example: if $M$ is a finitely generated module over a PID $A$ with invariant factors $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ then it’s $i$-th Fitting ideal is $(a_{n-i}\ldots a_1)$.  In particular $F_0$ is the product of the $a_i$‘s (so the cardinal it y of $M$ if $A=\mathbb Z$ and $M$ is finite).

Comment: This is not an answer, but I wanted to mention there is a vibe of a "derived functor" here; namely you are resolving your sheaf with a vector bundle. But I can't quite make this work.